# Grepping a single line from iftop

Tags: linux, bash, grep, strings

```
iftop -t -L1 -s1
```

**Output:**

[image]

```
iftop -t -L1 -s1 | grep "Total send and receive rate:"
```

**Output:**

[image]

How can I grep just the "Total send and receive state:" line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `iftop` is writing the unwanted lines to `STDERR`. To remove those for your `grep` use a command line as follows.

```
iftop -t -L1 -s1 2> /dev/null | grep "Total send and receive rate:"
```